# Adding Scheduler in AngularJS v1.4.7 application

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I've been given an existing application written in AngularJS v1.4.7 and I've been asked to add a scheduler to it where I should show events that're present on a DB Table.

I state that I'm totally new to Angular and what I've done till now is simply to add combo/textbox to the existing app. We've as well a Telerik license but I've not be able to understand if there's support for the [Telerik Scheduler](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/angular)

If it's not possible, any opensource library?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There certainly seem to be support for angular 1.x. In fact the page you link to say it all. Include `kendo.directives` as a dependency and follow the example.

Comment: ok but I don't understand if it's a native angular or a kendoui with angular support...looking at the controls here https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/ it doesn't shows